# Mapbox Xamarin.Forms black map on Android (Naxam.Mapbox.Form)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.android, mapbox

I have created an empty Xamarin.Forms project. Installed all required nugets. Added accessToken to MainActivity.OnCreate. Added a map to the start page and got a black screen.

(And maybe someone has a working Xamarin.Forms project using Naxam.Mapbox.Form?)

MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Com.Mapbox.Mapboxsdk.Mapbox.GetInstance(this, MAPBOX_TOKEN);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.Mapbox.Forms"
             x:Class="MapBoxEmpty.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <local:MapView x:Name="map" 
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       MapStyle="LIGHT" 
        />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

App:

[image]

What's wrong?

P.s. Haven't looked at iOS.

[Dropmefiles - Test project](https://dropmefiles.com/IbcPE)

Comment: did you look at the demo project in their github?  Have you set the permissions and services as described in the docs?  Have you checked your log output for any relevant messages?

Comment: Yes, I added all permissions, service, token. As in the documents and part as in the demo project. But looking at the demo project they have doesn't help, since it's not Xamarin.Forms. More precisely, Naxam.Mapbox.Form is not used :C

Comment: what are you talking about?  The demo is obviously a Forms project.  It does not use the nuget package because it instead links directly to the source.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Thank you.

But, have you tried running this project? It swears at me for non-existent versions of packages, and for a huge number of classes/ interfaces/etc. not found.

Almost the same problem as it: 
https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms/issues/113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to define the style of map in the page's code-behind file, not in the xaml...